# Fell for fake sugar daddy. How do I get out?

Tags: scams, sugar-daddy

I fell on hard times and for the first time I attempted to get a sugar daddy.

He asked for my bank account login info and reluctantly I gave it to him even though I knew I shouldn't have.

Short story, I figured out he's fake and called him out on it after he made a couple of mobile deposits. Every time he made a mobile deposit he would go in there and take a third of the money he deposited.

I also noticed he somehow used an old check I deposited and changed it and used it again.

I got him to admit he wasn't who he claimed to be and I changed my login info. He claimed he could still see how much money was in my account and sent me a screenshot of how much money was in the account with the amount and "Chase checking" before it. That was the only information in the screenshot.

He also threatened to get me in trouble with the law if I didn't send him more money. I changed my login info again just in case but I could really use some advice on what should I do next.

Comment: Why do you keep changing your login info? You need to change your bank number. Visit the bank and request new account numbers, which would most likely involve closing and reopening a separate account

Comment: @TrevorKS it's a good step to take immediately (you can do it while the bank is closed). Changing it a second time probably didn't do anything, though.

Answer (score 20):

Close the account. Notify the bank that you suspect a scam has happened with your bank account being involved.

Notify local police authorities.

Talk to a lawyer before you do any of the above or anything at all.

Comment: I would go ahead and close the account immediately. Then talk to a lawyer. And then, if the lawyer advised so, talk to the police.